# Removing Overlapping sites within Data Frame in R

Tags: r

I have a dataframe which contains overlapping sites, I want to be able to remove these overlapping site according to this rule.

End(B) > Start(A) & End(A) > Start(B) then we remove site B

For example ,

```
   Chrom        Start   End          
  scaffold_98   8309   8313    
  scaffold_98   8311   8320      
  scaffold_98   8811   8815
```

In this case, I should remove site (8311,8320) because it overlaps with (8309,8313).
Is there a fast way to do it when we are working with a large data.

Comment: You want to be looking up R/Bioconductor package `GenomicRanges` and methods around `findOverlaps`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `GenomicRanges` is not critically necessary here, but I recommend its use for more complex operations involving genomic coordinates. It is a very powerful library, and has been designed for these kind of operations.

Here is a solution using `findOverlaps::GenomicRanges`.

1. Load the library.

   ```
   library(GenomicRanges);
   ```
2. Read-in the sample data and turn into `GRanges` object.

   ```
   df <- read.table(text =
       "Chrom        Start   End
     scaffold_98   8309   8313
     scaffold_98   8311   8320
     scaffold_98   8811   8815   ", header = T)

   gr <- makeGRangesFromDataFrame(df);
   ```
3. Select for non-overlapping regions using `findOverlaps`.

   ```
   gr[unique(findOverlaps(gr, type = "any", select = "first"))];
   #GRanges object with 2 ranges and 0 metadata columns:
   #         seqnames       ranges strand
   #            <Rle>    <IRanges>  <Rle>
   #  [1] scaffold_98 [8309, 8313]      *
   #  [2] scaffold_98 [8811, 8815]      *
   #  -------
   #  seqinfo: 1 sequence from an unspecified genome; no seqlengths
   ```

Comment: Glad it helped @user12; `GenomicRanges` is a very powerful library, designed for these kind of operations; I can highly recommend its use. I can almost guarantee that it will make your life a lot easier further down the track. PS. Please consider closing the question by setting the check-mark next to the solution that answers your question best.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your df is ordered based on the start column, this might work:

```
remove <- vector()
for (i in 2:nrow(df)){
  if(df[i,3] > df[i-1, 2] && df[i-1, 3] > df[i, 2]) {
    remove <- append(remove, i)
  }
}

df[-remove,]
```